# How can I put a picture on my keyboard?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

**How can I put a picture on my keyboard**

So I'm working on a custom keyboard in IOS 8
Simple code here

> https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard

I want to know if I can change the background of the keyboard!
Can I put a picture on the background of the keyboard by fixing the number of images defined Rausch and simply just choose by pressing ...?

**I try to do it in this way:**

> In the window Main.storyboard
>
> I have a view named - Hosting Controller App View
>
> Class: HostingAppViewController

I added another view named -Catboard Banner
Class: CatboardBanner

I added a button in the view - Hosting Controller App View
To go to view - Catboard Banner

Then I added a button to go back to view - Hosting Controller App View

**My question is this:
When I try to add a second button within view - Catboard Banner and I want this button will put a picture on the background of my keyboard by pressing the button
As soon as I press my app crashes
Is there a way to do something to control my keyboard out the window view - Catboard Banner**

**ViewController.swift**

```
     import UIKit
class HostingAppViewController: UIViewController {
```

**KeyboardViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox
import AVFoundation


let metrics: [String:Double] = [
    "topBanner": 30
]

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
```

**CatboardBanner.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CatboardBanner: ExtraView {
```

Comment: What's "Rausch"?  Why did you remove the sample code you had originally posted?

Comment: I think I did not explain right :)